# C# Multi-dimensional Array

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

I'm trying to build a multi-dimensional array to store integer arrays.

```
Array[] TestArray = new Array[2];

for(int i = 0; i < TestArray.Length; i++)
{
   TestArray[i] = new int[5];
}
```

How do I go about accessing the newly created members of the Array? I am not sure how to access the newly created arrays in the array although I can see that they're properly created and stored when debugging in Visual Studio.

Comment: Why don't you use a `List<List<int>>` ?

Comment: Why are you not using a strongly type array for TestArray?

Comment: Did you look [Multidimensional Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)??

Comment: I'll look up the difference between multidimensional and jagged arrays  in a bit but is there an industry convention to not taking my initial approach? It seems like a valid approach as far as memory management and manipulation

Answer (score 12):

If you want an array of integer arrays, then you should declare it as such:

```
int[][] testArray = new int[2][];

for(int i = 0; i < testArray.Length; i++)
{
   testArray[i] = new int[5];
}
```

Arrays of arrays are called [Jagged Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) (in contrast to [Multidimensional Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to access fourth item in the second array:

```
int value = ((int[]) TestArray.GetValue(1))[3];
```

Although you would have much less trouble working with jagged arrays:

```
int[][] TestArray = new int[2][];
for (int i = 0; i < TestArray.Length; i++)
{
    TestArray[i] = new int[5];
}
```

or multidimensional arrays:

```
int[,] TestArray = new int[2,5];
```

Answer (score 1):

`T[][]` is the syntax you are looking for.

```
int[][] test = new int[2][];  //Declaring the array of arrays.

for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
{
    test[i] = new int[5];  //Instantiating a sub-arrays.
    for (int x = 0; x < test[i].Length; x++)
        test[i][x] = x + i;  //Filling a sub-arrays.
}

foreach (var array in test)  //iterating over the array of arrays.
    Console.WriteLine("Array: " + string.Join(", ", array));  //using a sub-array
Console.ReadLine();
```

For more info:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Cast the TestArray element as an `int[]`.

```
Array[] TestArray = new Array[2];

for(int i = 0; i < TestArray.Length; i++)
{
   TestArray[i] = new [] { 2,3 };
}

var firstIndexOfFirstArray = ((int[])TestArray[0])[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If looking for integer array, try

```
int[][] testArray
```